# Automatically change or get src in JavaScript

Tags: javascript

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function() {
    projekktor('#player_a', {
    poster:'.jpg',
    title: 'girl cheated on jhon' ,
    playerFlashMP4: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
    playerFlashMP3: 'swf/StrobeMediaPlayback/StrobeMediaPlayback.swf',
    width: 920,
    height: 500,
    playlist: [
        {

        0: {src: "movie.mp4", type: "video/mp4"},

        }
    ]    
    }, function(player) {} // on ready 
    );
});
</script>
```

How do I put (WWW.EXAMPLE.COM.mp4) on **"movie.mp4"** automatically in javascript **"movie.mp4"** changes with `www.example.com`

such as 0:

```
{src: "movie.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
```

replace with 0:

```
{src: "video.mp4", type: "video/mp4"}
```

without manually typing.

Comment: Can you clarify what you mean? where does the value for "link here" come from and what should  it change to?

Comment: such as "link here" is "movie.mp4" how do i change it with without manually typing. how can i make it automatically replace "movie.mp4" to "video.mp4"   when JavaScript load.

Comment: You should use variables in the first place, instead of string literals. Changing the value of a variable is easy. Rewriting the source code is both difficult and pointless in your case.